# What results from the reaction of 5-bromopentan-1-ol and NaOH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, halides

In our chemistry class, we noted three molecules that result from the reaction:

1. pentane-(1,5)-diol

[image: pentane-(1,5)-diol]

This one is simple to understand, simply a nucleophilic substitution between $\ce{Br^-}$ and $\ce{OH^-}$.

2. (1,5)-epoxypentane

[image: (1,5)-epoxypentane]

<s>This is the main result, resulting from the intramolecular esterification of the two $\ce{OH^-}$ groups of the previous molecule.</s> **This is wrong, please see the explanation 
by  ringo**

3. 4-penten-1-ol

[image: 4-penten-1-ol]

This one, I don't understand. How is this a possible result? Could anyone help me understand? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three reactions are:

An $\mathrm{S_N2}$:

[image]

Deprotonation followed by an intramolecular Williamson ether synthesis ($\mathrm{S_N2}$):

[image]

An $\mathrm{E2}$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the illustration, that made it much easier to understand. Would you mind me asking what software do you use to draw the equations?

Comment: ChemDraw. If you're at a university, they likely have a subscription and can get you a copy for free.